# Bitcoin will not open instead I see: error loading blkindex.dat

Tags: client

I have downloaded it onto my windows pc 3 separate times and each time it goes to start the program it shows the bitcoin wallet "loading addresses", then it's "loading block index" then my computer makes a noise and I receive this: **error loading blkindex.dat**. I click OK and it disappears with no options on how to fix.

I'm not very computer savvy. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Close the client, go to C:\Users\(Your Username)\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin and delete everything in the folder **except for wallet.dat - do not delete wallet.dat under any circumstances** (and empty your Recycle Bin), then restart the client. Somehow your block index file became corrupted.

Comment: Do not delete your wallet!

Comment: You can get a copy of the blockchain from http://eu1.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/

Comment: telling people to delete their wallet is a ( very ) bad idea . . .

Comment: @David and neofutur: I agree entirely, but the question stated, at least in the way I read it, that she had just installed it and never actually transferred Bitcoins, in which case deleting a wallet is irrelevant.

Comment: @BinaryMage I agree that in the case of this one question it sounds like the user had an empty wallet, but in the interest of providing good advice to future readers of this question for whom the situation might be somewhat different, I've edited in a warning re:wallet.dat. Good answer, though!

Comment: @DavidPerry Good point, thanks for the edit.

Comment: No problem! In some strange way it's almost like maintaining the quality of the site is my job... ;-)

Comment: We only need to delete blkindex.dat right? Why do we need to delete the other files?

Comment: I don't find any folder named AppData in Users.

Comment: @Masud It is often hidden. You could just try typing the Appdata after you home folder on the field on top of the explorer window

Comment: This does not work on my laptop, and I got 1 transaction running currently, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I just had to delete blkindex.dat. It's a little painful since you have to re-download that ~2GB file, but it worked for me.